# HighCharts Pie Chart - Displaying multiple series values in Tooltip

Tags: charts, highcharts, tooltip, formatter, pie-chart

I'd like to build a pie chart using HighCharts that shows two values. The one is a the value upon which the percentage breakdown is based - call it unit. The other value is the cost value. I want to use a standard pie chart and not a Donut.

When clicking on tooltip, I'd want to show the name value pair as per normal e.g. May, 15 units but then also display a $ value. e.g.:

May: 
15 units
$63

Is there anyway in a pie chart in highcharts to pull in a second data set.

A Donut chart provide more flexibility but in this case the requirements is that the chart only displays the units and the tooltip displays the additional details.

Comment: Is the cost value a percentage as well or a static value?

Answer (score 1):

In data poin you can set additional paramter and then disaply in by tooltip formatter like in the example:

```
tooltip: {
        formatter: function () {
            if (this.point.options.extraValue) return 'name: ' + this.key + ' <br/>y:' + this.y + '<br/>Extra value' + this.point.options.extraValue;
            else return 'name: ' + this.key + ' <br/>y:' + this.y;
        }
    },
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Fux94/2/